# How to invert a 3x3 matrix with each element being a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: c++, filter, matrix, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement a Kalman filter for data fusion in C++. As part of the project, I need to implement a function to calculate the inverse of a 3x3 matrix that has each element being a 3x3 matrix itself. Could you help me solve this problem? I would prefer a solution that requires the least amount of calculations (most CPU efficient).

Also another question, since the Kalman filter depends on the inverse matrix, how should I handle the case when the matrix is not invertible?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: You need a mathematical description before you can write a computer function.  Do you have a mathematical algorithm?

Comment: Is it even possible to invert a matrix of matrices? I'm really wondering here... Only possible thing I see is inverting each of the sub-matrices, but don't really know if that would be any good.

Comment: @Xeo: Good point...I suppose one could identify "1" with the 3x3 identity matrix, "0" with the 3x3 zero matrix, + and * with matrix addition and multiplication respectively. But matrix multiplication isn't commutative, so I don't know if the algebra would work out. But it makes me wonder if just treating Tuan's structure as a 9x9 matrix of reals, then inverting that, makes sense in this context.

Comment: @Jim: Well, depends on wether Tuan needs the matrix as a whole or just the sub-matrices really... Because I really can't think of any situation where you'd need a matrix of matrices. If he needs the matrix as a whole, then treating it as a 9x9 matrix would work I suppose.

Comment: @aschepler: I am trying to use the algorithm to invert a 3x3 matrix using the determinant (det) and treat each sub matrix like a number but it doesn't work. Since each element is a matrix, the determinant turns out to be a matrix and not a number.

Comment: @Jim,Xeo: unfortunately I need to consider each matrix individually and not just a big 9x9 matrix. This matrix is used to model a land vehicle dynamics. It includes position, velocity and acceleration in North, East and Down directions, hence a 3x3 matrix of 3x3 matrices. Here is a link to the original document that describes this problem: http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~fcaron/Publications/J_Information_Fusion_2004.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "small matrix" which is each element of a "big matrix", which contains pointers to the "small matrix", so reversing the "big matrix" will take as long as reversing a normal matrix of integers.

Probably this is the fastest algorithm you can do but does it fit in your implementation? How are your matrix declared?

Comment: my matrix is implemented similar to your idea, the big matrix contains the pointers to the small matrices. Then I inverse it using the algorithm to inverse a 3x3 matrix of real numbers but look like it's not correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Tuan Nguyen: so you're not getting run-time/compile-time errors of any kind? What does the debugger say?

Comment: No, the program compiles and runs fine. However, upon re-reading the Kalman filter document again I realized the small 3x3 matrices are treated like "blocks" inside the bigger matrix. So overall the big matrix is just a regular 9x9 matrix like Jim and Xeo suggested above.